# javascript validation error "Please use POST request"

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle

I am new to javascript.

I have tried JS validations and got the following error.

```
The error is {"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

Here the link. 
http://jsfiddle.net/H5JWe/

Thanks in advance

Comment: add `method="post"` to form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to submit a form through jsfiddle. It doesn't like that

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H5JWe/4/)

```
$.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function (value, element) {
    return $('#user_offer_type').val() != "";
}, "*select a offer type");

$("#user_form").validate({
    messages: {
        user_offer_type: {
            notEqual: "Select a offer type"
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {

    }
});
```

Will stop the submit button from submitting the form